# Handling multiple versions of same library in SBT

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, guava

I have a Spark project in Scala in which I'm trying to use `google-cloud-storage` dependency. Following are the dependencies added in by `build.sbt`

```
val sparkVersion  = "2.2.0"
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-storage" % "1.55.0",
"com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.1"
```

Now when I build the jar and run it I get following Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Upon googling I found out that it is caused because of multiple versions of `Guava` on my classpath.

In an attempt to resolve the issue I excluded `Guava` from `google-cloud-storage` dependency.

```
"com.google.cloud" % "google-cloud-storage" % "1.55.0" exclude("com.google.guava", "guava"),
```

But then I got following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/storage/StorageOptions
```

This error means that now there was no `Guava` jars at classpath.

My question is how is that possible before excluding guava I was getting error due to multiple version at classpath, how come I get no guava jars found error when I exclude one version of it.

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add the `guava` dependency as an explicit dependency:

```
libraryDependencies +=  "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "newest_version"
```

To figure out the newest version you can use this Plugin: [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph)

Or check the `eviction warnings` in the SBT console.